# is there any google API to check and count number of Armor Policies rules defined under a project. i have to count number of custom rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-armor, security-policy

Is there any google API to check and count number of Armor Policies  rules defined under a project. i have to count number of custom rules so that once it crosses the quota  limit that is 20 then it should throw an error.

I Have to write a ansible script for the same to throw error msg if it crosses maximum quota for advanced custom rules

just like  this is the one,

- name: Call google API to check number of Armor Policies defined under this project

uri:

url: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ client_project }}/global/securityPolicies"

method: GET

validate_certs: yes

status_code:

- 200

return_content: yes

headers:

Authorization: Bearer {{ oauthcmd.stdout }}

Content-Type: "application/json"

register: list_policy_out

tags: network

- name: Check for the Armor Policies count

assert:

that:

- "{{ list_policy_out.json['items'] | length < 11 }}"

fail_msg: "armor policies limit reached"

In the same-way , is there any  Google API to check the  number of rules defined under this project

and its url , please

google API to check and count number of Armor Policies  rules defined under a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a gCloud command, `gcloud compute project-info describe --project PROJECT_NAME` and pull the number from the `metric: SECURITY_POLICY_CEVAL_RULES` stanza. It will list the current project quota and the number of rules in use.

There is a beta feature you could try to [pull the quota](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/manage-quota?hl=en#displaying_service_quota) for the specific resource.

Comment: just like  this is the one,

- name: Call google API to check number of Armor Policies defined under this project

uri:

url: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ client_project }}/global/securityPolicies

In the same-way , is there any  Google API to check the  number of rules defined under this project

and its url , please